# How to monitor browser activity in Java?

Tags: java

I have a Java program which needs to monitor each web page that the user views on the browser.  I need to get the current URL in the browser and call some methods with it. How will I do this in Java? I have thought of building an extension in JavaScript but my code in Java is complicated and I don't understand how I could link them together.

Thanks

Comment: Try JRobin. It will help

Comment: Do you have control over the server side? or client side? or both?

Comment: None at the moment. I don't really know how to go about it.

Comment: I have also tried using JNetPcap for capturing packets but I am not sure if I am following the right direction.